# Getting error DecimalFields must define a 'max_digits' attribute

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I'm having a problem with these DecimalField types.

I have the next model:

```
class Mediciones(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Nombre dispositivo')
    dispositivo = models.ForeignKey(Dispositivos, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    temperatura = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    humedad = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    ruido = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    c02 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    alerta = models.BooleanField(null=False)
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Fecha", blank = False)
```

As you can see, I have four DecimalField, and all of them have defined both "max_digits" and "decimal_places", and max_digits is greater than decimal_places. Despite of that, I'm getting errors "DecimalFields must define a 'max_digits' attribute." when I try to make a migration. Do you know why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome Lönk! Are you able to add your actual error with surrounding context. There might be something there to provide more information.

Comment: The errors are: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
mediciones_app.Mediciones.c02: (fields.E132) DecimalFields must define a 'max_digits' attribute.
mediciones_app.Mediciones.humedad: (fields.E132) DecimalFields must define a 'max_digits' attribute.
mediciones_app.Mediciones.ruido: (fields.E132) DecimalFields must define a 'max_digits' 
attribute.
mediciones_app.Mediciones.temperatura: (fields.E132) DecimalFields must define a 'max_digits' attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I have managed to solve. The problem was not with the syntax, it seemed to be with the Python cache. I realized that when changing some fields it kept coming out (although I deleted the ones that gave error), so I assumed that I was not checking the file. I deleted the "pychache" and "migrations" folders, did a new migration and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try reordering the parameters, so it will look like:

```
temperatura = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
humedad = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
ruido = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=7)
c02 = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=7)
```

It is the only thing that I think that can be wrong, I had this problem once, and I did this to solve it.

Comment: I tried this but i still get the same error. I really don't know what I'm doing bad...

Comment: Try migrating one field at a time, maybe it will help, that's error is not your fault tho, everything looks alright from what you showed in the post